# GraphQL queries with multiple aliases and Apollo (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, graphql, alias, apollo

I'm trying to fetch data from a single collection type of my Strapi backend into a Vue.js project using Apollo. It works well with a single alias, but I'm having troubles making it work with multiple aliases.

I'm getting my data from a collection type of "campaigns" which has a boolean field of "archive". I want to create an array of "campaigns" that contains all of the campaigns that haven't been archived (archive = false) as well as an array of "archive" that contains all of the archived ones (archive = true).

This is my code:

```js
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export default {
  name: "Campaigns",
  data() {
    return {
      campaigns: [],
      archive: []
    };
  },
  apollo: {
    campaigns: gql`
      query getCampaigns {
        campaigns: campaigns(where: { archive: "false" }, sort: "order:DESC") {
          name
          url
        }
        archive: campaigns(where: { archive: "true" }, sort: "order:DESC") {
          name
          url
        }
      }
    `
  }
```

The query returns an array of "campaigns", but the array of "archive" is still empty.

I've tried switching things up (put the archive alias first, switched the boolean values to make sure I can generally access the data of the archived campaigns etc.). The problem apparently lies with the "archive"-alias.

When I use the same query with Strapi's GraphQL playground I get the desired result:

```js
{
  campaigns: campaigns(where: { archive: "false" }, sort: "order:DESC") {
    name
  }
  archive: campaigns(where: { archive: "true" }, sort: "order:DESC") {
    name
  }
}
```

... returns ...

```js
{
  "data": {
    "campaigns": [
      {
        "name": "2020"
      },
      {
        "name": "2019"
      },
      {
        "name": "2018"
      },
      {
        "name": "2017"
      }
    ],
    "archive": [
      {
        "name": "2016"
      },
      {
        "name": "2015"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I make the query work in Vue.js with Apollo?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've found a solution. Technically speaking I guess these are separate queries (which sort of defeats the purpose of aliases if I'm correct) but it does what I want:

```js
  apollo: {
    campaigns: {
      query: gql`
        query {
          campaigns: campaigns(
            where: { archive: "false" }
            sort: "order:desc"
          ) {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      `
    },
    archive: {
      query: gql`
        query {
          archive: campaigns(where: { archive: "true" }, sort: "order:desc") {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      `
    }
  }
```

Apparently under some circumstance the initialization "apollo: { **XYZ**:" and the alias "query { **XYZ**:" have to match. I've seen in the docs that they don't necessarily have to match, but I don't fully understand when and why.

I guess I can't really tell what the initial parameter does.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `campaigns` as the key for your entire query, so you need to initialize your data like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    campaigns: {
      campaigns: [],
      archive: [],
    },
  };
},
```

Then you can access each list through the key (i.e. `campaigns.campaigns` and `campaigns.archive`).

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure though? When I initialize the data like this I'm still unable to access  `campaigns.campaigns` or `campaigns.archive` for that matter. I can still access `campaigns` like I've been able to before and `archive` is empty.

Also when I check in the Vue tree with devtools all I see is...
"$apolloData > campaigns: Array[4] > 4 Objects containing 2017-2020"
Same with the data below.

Comment: Shoot. Sorry, it's been a bit since I last used Vue. I [think](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/249) for multiple queries you may have to use the `result` option to manually set the data yourself, in which case you can still initialize it as just `{campaigns: [], archive: []}` like you originally had.

Comment: Hmm the syntax is really confusing to me. I've noticed that some of the terms have to match in order to make the query work, but I'm not exactly sure why. I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around the nesting and what corresponds with what within the structure of a query. I'm also wondering if the syntax changed at some point because I keep reading that referenced docs are outdated and I tried stuff from tutorials and it just wouldn't work.. When I use result or update, the data property is apparently undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to do this is to use the `update` property: https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#name-matching

```
apollo: {
    campaigns: {
      query: gql`
        query {
          campaigns: campaigns(
            where: { archive: "false" }
            sort: "order:desc"
          ) {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      `
    },
    archive: {
      update: data => data.campaigns,
      query: gql`
        query {
          campaigns(where: { archive: "true" }, sort: "order:desc") {
            name
            url
          }
        }
      `
    }
  }
```